# File creation and compress on the same function

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x, zip

I have the reader read data from database time to time and generate csv files. I want to create the compress files while reading from database.

Currently I am creating the csv file and then creating the compress file.

```
def create_csv_file(data):
     filename = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".csv"
     filename_zip = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".zip"
     try:
           with open(filename, "w") as f:
               writer = csv.writer(f)
               for row in data:
                   writer.writerow(row)
               f.flush()

           with zipfile.ZipFile(filename_zip, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as myzip:
               myzip.write(filename, basename(filename))

     except Exception, e:
           print 'Error', e.message
```

I want to directly create zip file without .csv file and release the file open handle.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's no way to write a csv file incrementally with the `zipfile` module, you'll need to store all the CVS-formatted data somewhere. If the amount of data isn't really huge, memory is an obvious choice. @Davis Herring basically has the right idea, except in Python 2 you need to use [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) and in Python 3, [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO), as an intermediate buffer, before adding the formatted results stored in the buffer to the final `ZipFile` you want created.

Here's the whole thing, in all its glory. Note, I've left some debugging code in it, which you should be able to easily remove, since I've left your original code in as comments. BTW, it's possible for the two timestamps to be different since you call `time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")` twice.

```
import csv
import io
from pprint import pprint
from random import randint, seed
import time
import zipfile
import sys
InMemoryIO = getattr(io, 'BytesIO' if sys.version_info < (3,) else 'StringIO')

def create_csv_file(data):
    #filename = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".csv"
    #filename_zip = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + ".zip"
    # Use the same filenames everytime for testing.
    filename = "compress_me.csv"
    filename_zip = filename + ".zip"
    with InMemoryIO() as buffer:
        csv.writer(buffer).writerows(data)  # Convert data to csv format.
        with zipfile.ZipFile(filename_zip, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as myzip:
            myzip.writestr(filename, buffer.getvalue())


# Generate some random values to put in the csv file.
seed(42)  # Causes random numbers always be the same for testing.
data = [[randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(10)]
pprint(data)
create_csv_file(data)
```

Comment: Hi, in the line `csv.writer(buffer).writerows(data)` I get the following error: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera: That's because you're using Python 3. However this question is tagged "python-2.x", so my answer to it was written to run correctly with that version. I have modified it to now work in both.

Comment: Thanks, great answer by the way

Answer (score 1):

Use `ZipFile.writestr` (using [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/io.html#io.StringIO) to collect the `csv.writer` output) or (in Python 3.6) `ZipFile.open` in write mode.